# PHP: Reading word by word?

Tags: php, file, parsing

I am trying to read a file one word at a time. So far I have been able to use fgets() to read line by line or up to a certain amount of bytes, but that is not what I am looking for. I want one word at a time. up to the next white space, \n, or EOF.

Does anyone know how to do this in php. In c++ I just use the 'cin >> var' command.

Comment: Check this - http://www.phpbook.net/how-to-read-a-file-word-by-word-in-php.html

Comment: See this:- http://www.phpbook.net/how-to-read-a-file-word-by-word-in-php.html. Lol all copied from the same source :P

Answer (score 4):

you can do this by

```
$filecontents = file_get_contents('words.txt');

$words = preg_split('/[\s]+/', $filecontents, -1, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);

print_r($words);
```

this will give you array of words

Answer (score 4):

For some replies in this topic: I say this: **Do not reinvent the wheel.**

**In PHP use:**

```
str_word_count ( string $string [, int $format [, string $charlist ]] )
```

**format**:

0 = Return only the number of words;

1 = Return an array;

2 = Return an associative array;

**charlist:**

Charlist are characters which you consider a word.

[Function.str-word-count.php](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-word-count.php)

**[CAUTION]**

Nobody know anything about the size of your file content, if your file contents is big, exists many flexible solutions.

(^‿◕)

Answer (score 1):

You would have to use fgetc to get a letter at a time until you hit a word bountry then do something with the word. Example

```
 $fp = fopen("file.txt", "r");
 $wordBoundries = array("\n"," ");
 $wordBuffer = "";
 while ($c = fgetc($fp)){
     if (in_array($c, $wordBountries)){
         // do something then clear the buffer
         doSomethingWithBuffer($wordBuffer);
         $wordBuffer = "";
     } else {
        // add the letter to the buffer
        $wordBuffer.= $c;
     }
 }
 fclose($fp);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try `fget()` function which read file line by line and when you get one line from file you use `explode()` to extract word from line which separated by space.

Try this code:

```
$handle = fopen("inputfile.txt", "r");
if ($handle) {
    while (($line = fgets($handle)) !== false) {
        // process the line read.
        $word_arr = explode(" ", $line); //return word array
        foreach($word_arr as $word){
            echo $word; // required output
        }
    }
    fclose($handle);
} else {
    // error while opening file.
    echo "error";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Concerning "not reinventing the wheel", I agree.
The PHP reference for `str_word_count ( string $string [, int $format [, string $charlist ]] )`
says:

> "Note that multibyte locales are not supported."

If this is desired it might be useful to apply the other proposal:

```
$words = preg_split('/[\s]+/', $filecontents, -1, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);
```